# Making rigorous volumes by slicing

Tags: calculus

The volume $V$ of a circular cone of height $H$ and (base) radius $R$ is given by $\frac{1}{3} \pi R^2 H$.  My question relates to how a popular method of proof can be justified rigorously. I was first taught the proof of the volume via slicing, namely:

> **Method 1**
>
> Choose a point $x$ down the central axis of the cone.  Take a
>   horizontal slice of a circular cone of width $\delta x$.  Then the
>   volume of one such slice is given by $\pi (Rx/H)^2 \delta x$. 
>   Integrating, we get $$ V=\frac{\pi R^2}{H^2}\int^H_0 x^2 \, dx =
>  \frac{\pi R^2 H}{3}. $$ This gets the proof for the volume.

However, I am not sure how these steps can be justified.  My understanding is that one really ought to find the lower and upper Riemann sums, and show that they coincide in the limit.  Namely,

> **Method 2**
>
> Divide the cone into $k$ horizontal slices with even width.  By a calculation
>   I'm omitting we get
>
> 1. The Lower Riemann sum is given by $$\frac{\pi R^2 H}{k^3}\sum_{n=1}^k (k-n)^2.$$
> 2. The Upper Riemann sum is given by $$\frac{\pi R^2 H}{k^3}\sum_{n=1}^k (k-(n-1))^2.$$
>
> Then using the fact that $\sum_{i=1}^N i^2=\frac{N(N+1)(2N+1)}{6}$ for
>   any integer $N \geq 1$, we get that 
>   $$ \frac{\pi R^2 H}{6} \left(
>  1-\frac{1}{k}\right) \cdot 1 \cdot \left( 2-\frac{1}{k}\right) \leq V
>  \leq \frac{\pi R^2 H}{6} 1 \cdot \left( 1+\frac{1}{k}\right) \cdot
>  \left( 2+\frac{1}{k}\right). $$ So you get the result by taking $k
>  \rightarrow \infty$ and using the squeeze law.

This is really quite a bit of work.  This would be even more work for shapes different to a circular cone.  My question:  Can Method 1 be justified rigorously?

Comment: I find the title "Making rigorous volumes by slicing" easier to read, with adjective near the noun it acts.

Comment: No worries. done.

Comment: I want to tell you: You did comply very well with the make your effort part. thanks for that, there is a load of guys that don't write anything, just ask straight a question witouh putting work. You put even a little more than needed, keep the good work.

Comment: The classical proof is in Euclid XII.10. It's one of the longest propositions in the whole Elements. Archimedes attributes the result to Democritus, the first proof to Eudoxus; unsurprisingly, it uses the Method of Exhaustion.

Answer (score 1):

Method 1 is perfectly legit. This is just Fubini's theorem.